# EADDRINUSE error but only one application is running on the port

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server

After npm start, throws an EADDRINUSE error but I checked with lsof -i :PORT_IN_USE which only spits back one list. What else could possible be a problem? Any ideas are welcome

Comment: you can try to bind port twice and after second faulted whole process terminated and release port.

Comment: @vp_arth: a quick question, is it usual to have multiple npm running in cpu after npm starts? Considering that there was no npm running in CPU beforehand

Comment: what you mean under `npm starts`? It just shorthand for something like  `node myapp.js` ... See your `package.json` to see what actually runs

Comment: If `lsof` returns a result, there's something listening to that port already. It can't be the newly started process because that got the error.